# Наследование массива

Tags: javascript

Как сделать наследуемый "класс" от массива (`Array`)?

Стандартный подход, вида:

```
ArrayExt = function (){
  Array.apply( this, arguments );
}

tmp = function(){};
tmp.prototype = Array.prototype;
ArrayExt.prototype = new tmp();
ArrayExt.prototype.constructor = ArrayExt;
```

Работает не до конца...

```
test = new ArrayExt();

test[5] = 1;
test.length;// == 0, а должно быть 6
```

P.S:

Создание реального массива, с заменой его прототипа:

```
ArrayExt = function (){
  var arr = [];
  arr.__proto__ = ArrayExt.prototype;
  return arr;
}

tmp = function(){};
tmp.prototype = Array.prototype;
ArrayExt.prototype = new tmp();
ArrayExt.prototype.constructor = ArrayExt;
```

Не вариант ( т.к. строго говоря, `__proto__`  должно быть недоступным свойством ), хотя и работает

```
test = new ArrayExt();

test[5] = 1;
test.length;// == 6
```

P.P.S:

```
Array.prototype.newMethod = function(){}
```

Вообще не вариант (т.к. править встроенные объекты - не есть гуд).

Comment: Посмотрите [это](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM), можете перемотать большую половину, как я понимаю с ней у вас проблем быть не должно, а дальше там от и до подымается вопрос наследования.

Откровенно говоря, сейчас, возникло такое впечатление что вы, пока, так и не поняли что к чему и почему.

Ну и там естьшикарный пример имитации классов, очень простой и хитрый =)

Comment: И кстати - кто вам мешает проверять на существование то или иное свойство или метод прототипа? Вот здесь я имею введу:

      Array.prototype.newMethod = function(){}

И от переписывания вы всеравно не уходите, как-то непонял этого момента...

Answer (score 2):

Так тоже не вариант ?

```
function MyArray() {
    this.__proto__ = Array.prototype;
}

function test1()
{
    var t = new MyArray();
    t.push(3);
    alert(t.pop());
}
```

А что не так с кодом:

```
test = new ArrayExt();

test[5] = 1;
test.length;// == 6
```

Вроде всё верно.

---

```
function extend(Child, Parent) {
    var F = function() { }
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype
    Child.prototype = new F()
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child
    Child.superclass = Parent.prototype
}

function MyArray() {
}
extend(MyArray, Array);

MyArray.prototype.myMethod = function(){
    alert("Test Method");
}

function test1()
{
    var t = new MyArray();
    t.push(1);
    t.push(2);
    alert("Length: " + t.length);
    alert("Pop: " + t.pop());
    t.myMethod();
}
```

Так поидее "правильно" будет.

Comment: 1) Это:

   function MyArray() {
        this.__proto__ = Array.prototype;
    }

Не работает, т.к.:

   MyArray.prototype.myMethod = funciton(){};

   test = new MyArray();
   test.myMethod;// undefined

2) "test.length;// == 6" - не вариант, т.к. ручная замена прототипа объекта - не есть гуд

Comment: Вы скажите, что вы в итоге получить хотите.

Comment: Сделать "класс", чьим родителем является Array, максимально корректно с точки зрения спецификации языка

Comment: обновил ответ.

Comment: `Ваш код == Мой первый код == Стандартный подход`, и он НЕ верен...

Обычный массив:

    t = [];
    t[5] = 10;
    t.length;//6

Ваш код:

    t = new MyArray();
    t[5] = 10;
    t.length; //0

Comment: @timka_s - выносите уже из избы :D 

Зачем вам это???

Comment: Нужны методы: indexOfG[reat], indexOfE[qual]G[reat], indexOfL[ess], indexOfL[ess]E[qual]... Думаю куда их лучше засунуть)

Comment: В массив лепите, помню я тоже мучался изза неудовлетворенного чувства прекрасного в коде xD

Терпеть не долго - попускает быстро  =)

Answer (score 0):

Так вроде с использованием прототипного наследования больше никак.

Comment: КО в действии... Это не теоретический вопрос, а практический - как добиться нужного рез-та ( код ? )